# How can i code a time limit in my android game

Tags: android, time, limit

i have a quiz game for my android that has a time limit. what i want is there is a choices button that if you click one of the buttons it you will be automatically intent to the class next level but if you didnt answer or click any of the button you will be intent to the other class, thats why the game has a time limit. my problem is i dont know how to put a time limit that will intent or transfer you in another class automatically if you didnt click any of the button choices. i tried sleep but what happen is even i already clicked the correct answer and im on the next level class it will sleep to the class i intented to my sleep. please help me with my problem. i also try handler but didnt work

```
public class EasyOne extends Activity {
```

Button a, b, c;
TextView timer;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.easyone);
    a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ea1);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_eb1);
    c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ec1);
    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override   
           public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CORRECT!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new     Intent(getApplicationContext(),EasyTwo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private Runnable task = new Runnable() { 
    public void run() {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(task, 5000);
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TimesUp.class);
            startActivity(intent);

    }
};
```

Comment: Handler is the right approach to this solution, however you just need to make a slight adjustment. Add  field variable that will holder the time you want for each round, example `ROUND_LIMIT = 5` then in your `task` at the end you put `ROUND_LIMIT--` and you check for when this value hits 0 then launch the end round intent, else if the user answers before launch the correct or incorrect answer intent. Also in this case you would need to change the `postDelayed` timer to `1000` instead of `5000`

Comment: can you show me the code that ill should change and add? i really apriciate your help. thank you very much. "beginner in android"

Answer (score 0):

You should use a handler but in order to cancel the timeout you must remove the delayed message from the handler in your click listener code.

```
public class EasyOne extends Activity {

static private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        if (msg.what == 123) {
            ((EasyOne) msg.obj).onTimeout();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.easyone);
    a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ea1);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_eb1);
    c = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ec1);

    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(123,this);
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(msg,5000);

    a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"CORRECT!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mHandler.removeMessages(123,this);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EasyTwo.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}

private void onTimeout() {
    //your code
}
```

}

Comment: That's were you put the code that is supposed to be executed when the timeout is triggered. Looking at your code it would be Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TimesUp.class);startActivity(intent);